# Symfony (Doctrine) : Fixtures one to many relation with custom fields

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, fixtures

I'm looking to create fixtures file for the following schema (Movies library):

```
VodProgram:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    title:              { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    year:               { type: smallint }
    ...
  relations:
    VodPersons:
      class: VodPerson
        refClass: VodCasting
        local: program_id
        foreign: person_id
        foreignAlias: VodPrograms

VodPerson:
  columns:
    name:               { type: string(255), notnull: true }

VodCasting:
  columns:
    program_id:         { type: integer, primary: true }
    person_id:          { type: integer, primary: true }
    role:               { type: string(255) }
    rank:               { type: smallint }
  relations:
    VodProgram:         { onDelete: CASCADE, local: program_id, foreign: id }
    VodPerson:          { onDelete: CASCADE, local: person_id, foreign: id }
```

My problem is creating fixtures file with the "role" and "rank" fields present in the VodCasting table.

Here is my actual fixtures:

```
VodPerson:
  kosinski:
    name: Joseph Kosinski

VodProgram:
  tron:
    VodPersons: [kosinski] # where to put the role and rank infos ?
    title: Tron
    year: 2010
```

I tried something like :

```
VodProgram:
  tron:
    VodPersons:
      kosinski:
        rank: 1
    title: Tron
...
```

with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like that :

```
VodPerson:
  kosinski:
    name: Joseph Kosinski

VodProgram:
  tron:
    title: Tron
    year: 2010

VodCasting:
  tron_kosinski:
    role: 'Director'
    rank: 1
    VodPerson: kosinski
    VodProgram: tron
```